# Disabling ViewState for asp:Repeater increases load time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, viewstate, asprepeater

I have an **asp:Repeater** that is data bound to a collection of items once a button is clicked. Standard fare. However, if I **DISABLE** ViewState for the repeater, the time it takes to load the repeater after clicking the button takes dramatically longer. This is obviously the opposite of the effect I'm trying to achieve. By dramatic I mean ~10sec with ViewState enabled, and ~35sec with ViewState disabled.

I'm at a loss...

**NOTE:** In the event handler for the button click, I am also caching the data source. I am doing this regardless of whether I enable/disable ViewState. Is it possible that my caching is being ignored when ViewState is being used?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<asp:repeater id="niinMatchesTable" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
<headertemplate>
<table id="niinMatches" class="listing alternate">
  <tr>
    <th>QTY.</th>
    <th><asp:linkbutton runat="server" onclick="sortResultsTable" commandargument="niin-niin" text="NIIN" /></th>
    <th><asp:linkbutton runat="server" onclick="sortResultsTable" commandargument="niin-partnumber" text="PART #" /></th>
    <th>Cases</th>
  </tr>
</headertemplate>
<itemtemplate>
<tr class="odd">
  <td><asp:label runat="server" text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Quantity") %>' /></td>
  <td><asp:label runat="server" text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NIIN") %>' /></td>
  <td><asp:label runat="server" text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PartNumber") %>' /></td>
  <td><asp:label runat="server" text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Cases") %>' /></td>
</tr>
</itemtemplate>
<footertemplate>
  </table>
</footertemplate>
</asp:repeater>



protected void uploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fileUploader.HasFile)
    {   
        fileUploader.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/temp/inventory.xls"));
        var niinMatches = getNiinMatches(); // Populates object by parsing spreadsheet

        var absExp = System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration;
        var slidingExp = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        Cache.Insert("_niinMatches", niinMatches, null, absExp, slidingExp);

        niinMatchesTable.DataSource = niinMatches;
        niinMatchesTable.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would probably be easier to help if you provide the code you're working with.

Comment: if you disable the view-state then you need to re-bind the repeater in every post-back. Perhaps, your data is getting picked up from file instead of cached value on each post-back making it slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before jumping to conclusions i would get Firebug addon for firefox and check what takes so long. But I don't see any real gain of caching on button click, since each time the button is clicked cache will be updated... Unless there's another method that binds gridview to the cached dataset on each postback.